# Need Solution for browser compatibility issue

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, compatibility

Our application is running fine in chrome browser. But in Firefox some features and screens are not working properly. So it needs to  be fixed .How can i do that and  what could be the solution for that?

Comment: Not working? Any error messages? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No i'm not receiving any error messages , Getting UI breakage issues.          For example In chrome the loading mask is working fine. but in firefox the loading mask is not appearing.

Comment: You need to show the actual HTML and CSS code that is causing the problem so that it becomes reproducible for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to find out what is 'going on' is to debug the code in the browser.
Firefox has a built in debugger but i prefer to use a third party debugger called  [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/).

Answer (score 0):

You should give Firebug a try as indicated in the first answer. However as far as I know you had to install it as Add-on, it is not included in the distribution.

Comment: I already tried with some Add_on. But those were not working. Thank you for your response @sebastian

Comment: Can you please tell me Add_on ? @sabastian

Comment: Firebug is an extension  for the Firefox browser. Hence use: Extras -> Add-ons (select the Extensions tab in the Add-ons page) in Firefox to search for Firebug. More information about Firebug can be found [here](http://getfirebug.com/). There are a lot of extensions for Firebug (XPath, CSS, ...) and so. To get some help with Firebug check the [tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/web-development-tools/firebug-tutorials.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a little too general. Anyway, if the compatibility issue is about CSS style, you should check whether you are using WebKit-prefixed CSS only. For example, if you are using -webkit-animation, it would only work in Chrome and Safari. Actually you should set four CSS styles: -webkit-animation, -moz-animation, -o-animation and animation to make your code work in major browsers. There are some documents about Mozilla and WebKit CSS that might help:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Webkit_Extensions