# Which CSS property which don't dependent on Browser

Tags: css, angularjs, html

I'm having browser compatibility issue in my UI. In Firefox I'm facing some UI breakage issues, In chrome i don't have any issues.So my team said to try some CSS properties with don't dependent on browser that could be a solution for this.So anyone may know about this?

```
 <li align="center" ng-show="showLoadingIcon">
                <img src="app-vrm/img/loader.gif"/>
            </li>
```

This is what the code for that loading mask. If change align from center to right,left or justify .That is working fine in chrome but in Firefox the loading mask is loading always in left side. It should be displayed in the center of the screen

Comment: It'd be better if you showed what code you're using (HTML and CSS) and what specifically is breaking, then we can help you work around this. Right now this is too speculative.

Comment: Actually, never mind, you've [already asked about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409145/need-solution-for-browser-compatibility-issue). Please rather edit that other question than posting another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good starting point is to make sure you're starting from the same point by creating a reset.css file. This file makes sure that for each browser e.g. the margin-top for a P-tag is always 5px. There are plenty of resources on the web

Furthermore, you should have a look at W3Schools table for browser compatibility [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp).

Last but not least, be aware that some CSS3 tags are not implemented at all yet because they are 'too modern'. Or your browser is too old.

And a good CSS-validator might help. In Google Chrome (or Iron Browser, or Chromium) you can enable the developer tools and look at the console for errors, or install an extension (Web Developer for Firefox together with Firebug). Or if your site is online validate it with W3 [CSS validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a cross-browser centre alignment of image. Main useful thing is img having margin and display property. Please see working solution at this link:
URL: http://codepen.io/krunalv/pen/gborwo

```
 .loadingImage-wrapper li img{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;      
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Your changes is working in my local fine. But the problem  which i'm facing is different. The changes is not reflecting in firefox browser in chrome only the changes are working.. In Firefox the loading mask is always displaying in the left side only. I need solution that issue in Firefox.

Comment: You just need to remove align center from li no inline css or attribute for alignment should be used. Just simply below code for image: img { display:block; margin: 0 auto;} that's it. Should be working in all browsers.

Comment: Cannot judge the scenario without more description of the code. You might be facing the css overrides on image which can be debuged in console of browser.

Comment: i found the solution for that. Thanks for your responses for my questions ..Thanks a lot for you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue........ i changed the code instead of

```
align="center"
```

i added

```
style="text-align:center;"
```

So this property is working in Firefox as well.

I really want to thank the people who help me to find out the solution.I got many new things from you whenever you are giving some answers.